# Why `intersect` syntax does not work in R in an `if statement`?

Tags: r, if-statement, intersect

I know the syntax of an `IF` statement in R:

```
if (1==1){
  print("this is true")
}
```

And I know that the stuff between the `()` should be evaluated to a logical.  So, when I try this:

```
if (intersect(list(1),list(1,2)) != list()){
  print("this is also true")
}
```

I expected it to work, since the `intersect(list(1),list(1,2)) != list()` is evaluated as a logical type:

```
intersect(list(1),list(1,2)) == list()
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: The logical vector must be of length 1, which is not the case. You can test `length(intersect(list(1),list(1,2))) > 0`.

Comment: Logical *type*, yes, but zero length. That expression must evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Aren't you asking in this case if the length of the intersection is zero (as in `length(intersect(list(1),list(1,2))) == 0`) ?  When comparing lists it doesn't appear it is supported as in `list(1,2) == list(1,2)` gives the error `Error in list(1, 2) == list(1, 2) : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented`

Comment: I understand why @Roland suggestion works, but I'm still confused why I can't check if the resulting list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The logical operators are not appropriate for comparing list objects. List objects are a recursive type , not coercible to logical vectors without loss of structural information. The function for comparing lists is `identical`. It didn't seem reasonable to expect your operation to deliver TRUE since the intersection of `list(1)` and `list(1,2)` would not be `list()`, so I inverted the test to allow testing:

```
 if ( !identical(intersect(list(1),list(1,2)), list())) {
           print("this is also true")
         }
#[1] "this is also true"
```

And the intersection is `list(1)`:

```
if ( identical(intersect(list(1),list(1,2)), list(1))) {
   print("this is also true")
 }
#[1] "this is also true"
```